# Change from http to https using http4s

Tags: http, https, http4s

Is there any way to change a http server to https using the library http4s? (https://http4s.org/)

Comment: Can you please provide some more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found myself facing this same issue but I managed to solve it, here's the thing:

1. You need to look for the moment when you build your server, presumably with BlazeServerBuilder.
2. BlazeServerBuilder has the method "withSslContext(sslContext: SSLContext)" to enable SSL. Thus, all you need to do is create a SSLContext object and pass it to the server builder.

**Remember that you will probably have to store your SSL certificate in a keystore using Java's keytool utility before using it.**

#### SSL context and SSL certificate

How to create an SSL context with an SSL certificate is another question, but here is an interesting post that covers the process of getting a free certificate from Let's Encrypt, storing it in a keystore and using it from a Java application:  [Using Let's Encrypt certificates in Java applications - Ken Coenen — Ordina JWorks Tech Blog](https://ordina-jworks.github.io/security/2019/08/14/Using-Lets-Encrypt-Certificates-In-Java.html)

And here's the code I used for creating a SSLContext in Scala:

```scala
val keyStorePassword: String   = your_keystore_password
val keyManagerPassword: String = your_certificate_password
val keyStorePath: String       = your_keystore_location

val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType)

val in = new FileInputStream(keyStorePath)
keyStore.load(in, keyStorePassword.toCharArray)

val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm)
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray)

val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm)
trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore)

val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers, new SecureRandom())
sslContext
```

Comment: example: https://github.com/http4s/http4s/blob/main/examples/src/main/scala/com/example/http4s/ssl.scala

Comment: A tutorial to add Letsencrypt to a http4s project can be found here https://www.scalawilliam.com/letsencrypt-http4s/